# Blur event is fired on focused parent element if focused element's child is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to create a part of a form where if you click on a select, a checkbox field should popup and if you click anywhere else again, this field should disappear. I would like to do this with focusing the field after clicking on the select, but for some reason, my checkbox field loses its focus not only when you click anywhere else out of it, but even when you click on a label of a checkbox INSIDE of it. So the problem is that I am focusing an element in which I click on a label and the focused parent element loses its focus for some reason I can not figure out.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/RELuL/2/

Any helps appreciated!

P.S.:

Just some bonus question :) As you can see, if you click on the select input, my hidden checkbox section is displayed a little late, it is not shown instantly which looks a little bad. Any tips how to optimize this?

EDIT: I use Firefox 13.0.1

Comment: So is this form a select or checkbox, and why do you change it?

Comment: It is a select, but if clicked on it, it has to popup this checkbox box. It is a task I have to do, I dont agree with the method, but it must be done like this.

Comment: Stupid question - why do you do this instead of using a plain multi-slectbox or those checkboxes directly? Don't make it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: As I have said in my last comment: "It is a task I have to do, I dont agree with the method, but it must be done like this."

Comment: @skywlkr Question answered and bonus too :)

Comment: For the bonus question bind `mousedown` event on your dropdown instead of `click`. This will prevent it from opening the dropdown giving it a much better experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on a `<label>`, the browser focuses the associated input field. So focus leaves the parent and goes to the checkbox (and your blur event handler is called).

Instead of focusing the parent div and relying on it being blurred, attached a click handler to the document:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    multiSelectUpdate();
});

$('.multiselect.container').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // prevent click event from reaching document
});
```

Also, in Webkit clicking on `<select>` doesn't fire a click event. A workaround is to use the focus event instead.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/RELuL/17/)

Comment: This is the best solution so far, but I have upgraded it in a way that I only bind the click listener for the document after I have opened the select box and after it is closed, I unbind the click listener from the document, so it doesnt run the multiSelectUpdate() function everytime I click somewhere on the page. Thanks, bounty award is on its way!

Answer (score 0):

Ok two simple changes got this working first change the click listen on the select box to a [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) listener like so.

```
 $('.multiselector').mousedown(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        currentMulti = $(this).attr('id');
        thisOffset = $(this).offset();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#' + currentMulti + '-container')
            .css('top', thisOffset.top + 'px').show().attr("tabindex", -1).focus();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

this triggers before the box is able to comes up so it never shows.

Secondly the blur listener was believing it lost focus when a child got focus to fix this change to [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

```
 $('.multiselect.container').focusout(function() {
        multiSelectUpdate();
    });
```

This only fires when the selector loses focus even focus currently on child of selector.

Fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RELuL/15/)

enjoy :)

**EDIT**

For some reason blur fires multiple times on FF so to work round this use instead of blur mouseleave.

```
$('.multiselect.container').mouseleave(function() {
        multiSelectUpdate();
    });
```

Comment: I would like to accept it as an answer, but as you can see, your solution doesnt work perfectly, because if I click outside of the box, the container doesnt lose focus, the focusout event is not triggered.

Comment: @skywlkr try now seems i hadnt updated lol, it does fire just the fiddle hadnt got the focusout implemented

Comment: Yeah, it loses focus now, but at Firefox, it is still losing focus if I click on the labels. What do you test on? Because on Chrome, it is working, but it must work on FFox too.

Comment: @skywlkr I tested in chrome yes, in FF it blurred when yo clicked a child and triggered event a workaround is in the edit :)

Comment: I really appreciate the time and work you put in this solution, but I have to accept Jeffrey To's answer, because it is the closest for the thing I wanted to achieve. Mouseleaving is not the event I wanted to fire my function after :/ I wish I could give you some bounty points too, but I dont have any :P But thanks again and have a nice day!